# Как вставить сообщение FacesMessage в p:message, обрабатываемое в бине?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

View

```html
<p:commandButton id="removeId"
    value="#{i18n['common.table.actions.delete']}"
    actionListener="#{bean.remove()}" />                               
<p:message for="removeId" />
```

Bean

```java
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("removeId", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Error", "Error"));
```

C такой конфигурацией не проходит

Comment: Попробуй `<p:message for="removeId" autoUpdate="true"  /> `

Answer (score 1):

Нужно обновить message после действия, которое может послать сообщение.

```
<p:commandButton id="removeId"
    value="#{i18n['common.table.actions.delete']}"
    actionListener="#{bean.remove()}" update="msg" />                               
<p:message id="msg" for="removeId" />
```